# Accessing Rest URL from inside a servlet

Tags: spring, rest, url

I am trying to create a servelet that will accept a post from any url so I have created the following RestController:

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/**")
public @ResponseBody String processPost(@RequestBody String msg) 
 {
 // work done in here
 return msg;
 }
```

Is there a way I can find out the url that was used from inside the processPost method?

Comment: You're thinking completely backwards. The `DispatcherServlet` already does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Spring allows flexible method signatures so you can use the `HttpServletRequest` object directly:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/**")
public @ResponseBody String processPost(@RequestBody String msg,
         HttpServletRequest request) {
     String thePath = request.getRequestURI();
     return msg;
 }
```

Comment: got the point but consider review 13.11.4. Supported handler method arguments and return types from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/mvc.html, that will help you a lot.